# Français moderne

Tags: sens, histoire, littérature

Je suis en train d'étudier français et je veux lire quelques romans. Quels romanciers ne sont pas trop anciens pour cet objectif? Je pense essentiellement à Proust, Maupassant, Flaubert, Hugo et Stendhal.

Comment: Mon seul conseil est : lis le genre qui te plaît car tu n'apprendras jamais mieux qu'en lisant le **genre** qui te plaît. Sans considération donc pour l'époque. Aucun romancier ne peut être tenu pour "trop ancien" si 1/ tu le comprends 2/ il sait te toucher ici et maintenant.

Comment: Avant le 17è siècle, il est possible de rencontrer certaines expressions ou orthographes qui ne sont plus d'actualité, mais globalement depuis cette période la langue française est restée plutôt stable.

Comment: Si tu aimes la littérature qui décrit beaucoup ses personnages, Maupassant/Flaubert/Hugo le font très bien (voir trop bien), je pense notamment à *Bel-Ami* de Maupassant (qui ne m'a pas du tout plu lors de mes études)

Answer (score 2):

Pour commencer, je t'invite à lire des romans que tu as déjà lu (et aimé) dans ta langue natale; cela t'aidera beaucoup à comprendre le sens de l'histoire (même si tu connais déjà la fin).

Une grande partie des livres ont été traduit en français (un peu comme pour les autres langues), on peux penser par exemple aux romans de J.K Rowling ou Elena Ferrante, qui ont notamment l'avantage d'être traduit dans un français **moderne**.

Si tu veux lire absolument de nouveaux livres, nous sommes plusieurs à pouvoir te conseiller de très bons livres (datant du XVIIIème siècle ou récent)

*PS: je pourrais te conseiller plusieurs séries de livres fantastiques illustrant d'excellentes thématiques*

Comment: J'ai lu Harry Potter en Anglais, et il n'est pas toujours facile d'y différencier les mots réels qu'on ne comprend pas des mots inventés (moldus, mange-morts, ...) même si effectivement avec un peu de bon sens en connaissant les livres dans sa langue ca aide. Je conseillerais néanmoins d'avoir déjà un niveau correct afin de pouvoir plus facilement faire la différence.

Comment: @LaurentS. C'est le style de l'héroique-fantaisie, il est très rare de ne voir aucun mots ou noms inventés dans ce genre de livre, ce n'est pas les plus simples à lire dans une langue non natale, mais pas les pires non plus